# Apache Ignite.NET: some Ignite nodes fail to start up after update to v2.9 - stack smashing detected

Tags: ignite

I am running Apache Ignite .Net in a Kubernetes cluster on Linux nodes.

Recently I updated my ignite 2.8.1 cluster to v2.9. After the update some of the services being parts of the cluster fail to start up with the following message:

*** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated

Interestingly, most often it happens with the 2nd instances of the same microservice. The first instances usually start up successfully (but sometimes the first instances fail, too). Another observation is that it happens to the nodes which publish Service Grid services. Sometimes a full cluster recycle (killing all the nodes then spinning them up again) helps to get all the nodes to start up, sometimes not.

Did I mess up something during the update? What should I check first of all?

Below is an excerpt from the Ignite log.

```
2020-12-08 22:05:25,683 [1] DEBUG  [(null)] - Classpath resolved to: /app/libs/spring-jdbc-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/spring-messaging-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/ignite-indexing-2.9.0.jar;/app/libs/opencensus-impl-core-0.22.0.jar;/app/libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.1.jar;/app/libs/lucene-analyzers-common-7.4.0.jar;/app/libs/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.10.1.jar;/app/libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;/app/libs/spring-context-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/tyrus-standalone-client-1.15.jar;/app/libs/jackson-core-2.10.1.jar;/app/libs/spring-core-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/control-center-agent-2.9.0.0.jar;/app/libs/commons-codec-1.11.jar;/app/libs/disruptor-3.4.2.jar;/app/libs/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar;/app/libs/spring-tx-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/spring-core-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar;/app/libs/spring-beans-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/h2-1.4.197.jar;/app/libs/ignite-core-2.9.0.jar;/app/libs/spring-aop-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/reflections8-0.11.7.jar;/app/libs/cache-api-1.0.0.jar;/app/libs/spring-websocket-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/lucene-core-7.4.0.jar;/app/libs/jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar;/app/libs/ignite-spring-2.9.0.jar;/app/libs/grpc-context-1.19.0.jar;/app/libs/lucene-queryparser-7.4.0.jar;/app/libs/spring-web-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar;/app/libs/ignite-shmem-1.0.0.jar;/app/libs/guava-26.0-android.jar;/app/libs/spring-expression-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/spring-jdbc-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/spring-messaging-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/ignite-indexing-2.9.0.jar:/app/libs/opencensus-impl-core-0.22.0.jar:/app/libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.1.jar:/app/libs/lucene-analyzers-common-7.4.0.jar:/app/libs/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.10.1.jar:/app/libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/app/libs/spring-context-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/tyrus-standalone-client-1.15.jar:/app/libs/jackson-core-2.10.1.jar:/app/libs/spring-core-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/control-center-agent-2.9.0.0.jar:/app/libs/commons-codec-1.11.jar:/app/libs/disruptor-3.4.2.jar:/app/libs/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/app/libs/spring-tx-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/spring-core-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/app/libs/spring-beans-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/h2-1.4.197.jar:/app/libs/ignite-core-2.9.0.jar:/app/libs/spring-aop-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/reflections8-0.11.7.jar:/app/libs/cache-api-1.0.0.jar:/app/libs/spring-websocket-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/lucene-core-7.4.0.jar:/app/libs/jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:/app/libs/ignite-spring-2.9.0.jar:/app/libs/grpc-context-1.19.0.jar:/app/libs/lucene-queryparser-7.4.0.jar:/app/libs/spring-web-4.3.29.RELEASE.jar:/app/libs/ignite-shmem-1.0.0.jar:/app/libs/guava-26.0-android.jar:/app/libs/spring-expression-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:
2020-12-08 22:05:25,860 [1] DEBUG  [(null)] - JVM started.
[22:05:26,184][INFO][main][XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/app/./kubernetes.config
...
2020-12-08 22:05:37,936 [70] INFO  org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander [(null)] - Completed rebalance future: RebalanceFuture [state=STARTED, grp=CacheGroupContext [grp=ignite-sys-cache], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=82, minorTopVer=0], rebalanceId=1, routines=4, receivedBytes=1200, receivedKeys=0, partitionsLeft=0, startTime=1607465137846, endTime=-1, lastCancelledTime=-1, next=null]
2020-12-08 22:05:37,936 [70] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander [(null)] - Partitions have been scheduled to resend [reason=Rebalance is done, grp=ignite-sys-cache]
2020-12-08 22:05:37,937 [70] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander [(null)] - Finished rebalancing partition: [grp=ignite-sys-cache, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=82, minorTopVer=0], supplier=12ca76f0-3286-4779-a426-408d5d6cf226, p=61]
2020-12-08 22:05:37,937 [70] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander [(null)] - Will not request next demand message [grp=ignite-sys-cache, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=82, minorTopVer=0], supplier=12ca76f0-3286-4779-a426-408d5d6cf226, rebalanceFuture=RebalanceFuture [state=STARTED, grp=CacheGroupContext [grp=ignite-sys-cache], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=82, minorTopVer=0], rebalanceId=1, routines=4, receivedBytes=1200, receivedKeys=0, partitionsLeft=0, startTime=1607465137846, endTime=1607465137937, lastCancelledTime=-1, next=null]]
2020-12-08 22:05:37,943 [71] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerProcessor [(null)] - Grid runnable started: nio-acceptor-client-listener
2020-12-08 22:05:37,944 [72] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerProcessor [(null)] - Grid runnable started: grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0
2020-12-08 22:05:37,944 [1] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.IgniteServiceProcessor [(null)] - Started service processor.
2020-12-08 22:05:37,954 [73] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.ServiceDeploymentManager [(null)] - Grid runnable started: services-deployment-worker
2020-12-08 22:05:37,955 [73] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.ServiceDeploymentTask [(null)] - Started services deployment task init: [depId=ServiceDeploymentProcessId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=81, minorTopVer=0], reqId=null], locId=c894369e-d55b-4d7b-8e5e-c990d0547121, evt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c894369e-d55b-4d7b-8e5e-c990d0547121, consistentId=product-service-deployment-7c69d99ff6-vc6nb, addrs=ArrayList [10.0.2.27, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, product-service-deployment-7c69d99ff6-vc6nb/10.0.2.27:47500], discPort=47500, order=81, intOrder=44, lastExchangeTime=1607465137554, loc=true, ver=2.9.0#20201015-sha1:70742da8, isClient=false], topVer=81, msgTemplate=null, span=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@3f4cf36, nodeId8=c894369e, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1607465136027]]
2020-12-08 22:05:38,017 [73] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceProcessor [(null)] - Injecting resources [obj=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cluster.PlatformClusterNodeFilterImpl@5d421915]
2020-12-08 22:05:38,038 [1] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor [(null)] - REST processor started.
2020-12-08 22:05:38,056 [74] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor [(null)] - Grid runnable started: session-timeout-worker
2020-12-08 22:05:38,098 [32] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.timeout.GridTimeoutProcessor [(null)] - Timeout has occurred [obj=CancelableTask [id=d5e43644671-3ea29289-4345-4d80-8eab-97397473a5a9, endTime=1607465138070, period=10000, cancel=false, task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.ConnectionManager$$Lambda$307/57085696@6197e588], process=true]
2020-12-08 22:05:38,110 [1] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceProcessor [(null)] - Injecting resources [obj=org.gridgain.control.agent.processor.lifecycle.ClusterLifecycleProcessor$$Lambda$586/893320639@55cff952]
2020-12-08 22:05:38,142 [75] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager [(null)] - Message set has not been changed: GridCommunicationMessageSet [nodeId=3f89e86c-f636-4324-895b-1a77cec8ed11, endTime=1607465141249, timeoutId=8fe43644671-3ea29289-4345-4d80-8eab-97397473a5a9, topic=TOPIC_COMM_USER, plc=0, msgs=ConcurrentLinkedDeque [], reserved=false, timeout=5000, skipOnTimeout=true, lastTs=1607465136249]
2020-12-08 22:05:38,148 [1] WARN  org.gridgain.control.agent.ControlCenterAgent [(null)] - Current Ignite configuration does not support tracing functionality and Control Center agent will not collect traces (consider adding ignite-opencensus module to classpath).
2020-12-08 22:05:38,152 [1] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceProcessor [(null)] - Injecting resources [obj=org.gridgain.control.agent.ControlCenterAgent$$Lambda$591/1985869725@151335cb]
2020-12-08 22:05:38,175 [76] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager [(null)] - Message set has not been changed: GridCommunicationMessageSet [nodeId=3f89e86c-f636-4324-895b-1a77cec8ed11, endTime=1607465141249, timeoutId=8fe43644671-3ea29289-4345-4d80-8eab-97397473a5a9, topic=TOPIC_COMM_USER, plc=0, msgs=ConcurrentLinkedDeque [], reserved=false, timeout=5000, skipOnTimeout=true, lastTs=1607465136249]
2020-12-08 22:05:38,476 [73] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.service.ServiceDeploymentTask [(null)] - Calculated service assignment : [srvcId=56296344671-81118589-d216-4762-a835-3df2230389c5, srvcTop={c894369e-d55b-4d7b-8e5e-c990d0547121=1, 3f89e86c-f636-4324-895b-1a77cec8ed11=1}]
2020-12-08 22:05:38,484 [73] DEBUG org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.resource.GridResourceProcessor [(null)] - Injecting resources [obj=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.dotnet.PlatformDotNetServiceImpl@20119802]
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack smashing detected` usually indicates a `NullReferenceException` in C# code.

Set `COMPlus_EnableAlternateStackCheck` environment variable to `1` before running your app to see full stack trace (this works for .NET Core 3.0 and later).

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-troubleshooting#stack-smashing-detected-dotnet-terminated

Comment: Thank you, I'll try

Comment: Bravo, it helped even more that I could expect from your suggestion: after setting COMPlus_EnableAlternateStackCheck to 1 the nodes stopped crashing. Not sure why if the var was supossed to only reveal error details but thank you again!